# SQL Server 2008 stored procedure for a table having two foreign keys and both of them is a composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following tables :

```
create table ApartmentInfo(
     ApartmentId int primary key identity,
     ApName nvarchar(50))

create table [User](
     UserId int primary key identity,
     FirstName nvarchar(50),
     LastName    nvarchar(50),
     Username nvarchar(50),
     [Password] nvarchar(50),
     [Description] nvarchar(200))

create table ApUser(
     ApartmentId int foreign key references ApartmentInfo(ApartmentId),
     UserId int foreign key references [User](UserId),
     primary key(ApartmentId,UserId))
```

Summary of the usage is: suppose I have 10 apartments in my `Apartmentinfo` table and 3 users in the `[User]` table.

Now I want to write a stored procedure such that:

1. every `UserId` has all 10 `ApartmentId`'s, and whenever a new apartment is created in `ApartmentInfo` table it will also be added in `ApUser` table again having all 3 `userId`'s.
2. And if a new user is created in `User` table then it will also have all the 10 `ApartmentId`'s related with it in `ApUser` table.

Thanks in advance, I am new to SQL Server and I don't know how it can be done or not but, if it is possible then please let me know, I will be grateful to you, thanks.

Comment: If *every* user is linked to *every* apartment, for now and all time (so that any new users and apartments are also linked), why are you bothering to record that?

Comment: thank you for your reply, these users will have login credentials like username and password and they can only see the information of the apartments after logging in

Comment: But my point is about this table in the middle - if it's always containing *every* user and *every* apartment, there's no need to store that as a table - if you even *need* that result set, it's just a `VIEW` containing a `CROSS JOIN` between `User` and `ApartmentInfo`

Comment: ok, Thanks..now i understand, i can simply select all apartments as soon as user enter his login, so there is no point to give relation between ApartmentInfo table and User table. But, still if i want to do that, would it be possible...any clue then please tell, it will definately be helpful somewhere in my project, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not dead set on using a stored procedure this use case seems like an excellent fit for server side triggers:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[trigger_insert_apartment]'))
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_insert_apartment]
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_apartment
ON ApartmentInfo FOR INSERT 
AS INSERT ApUser(ApartmentId, UserId ) SELECT i.ApartmentId, u.UserId FROM [User] AS u, inserted AS i
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[trigger_insert_user]'))
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_insert_user]
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_user
ON [User] FOR INSERT 
AS INSERT ApUser(ApartmentId,UserId ) SELECT a.ApartmentId, i.UserId FROM ApartmentInfo AS a, inserted AS i
GO
```

These two triggers will insert all apartments or users into the apinfo table when you add a new user or apartment, and if I understood your question that was what you wanted?

Comment: thank you sir for your reply the question is exactly the same but as soon as i created the trigger i have recieved this error          Msg 2714, Level 16, State 2, Procedure trigger_insert_apartment, Line 3
There is already an object named 'trigger_insert_apartment' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 2, Procedure trigger_insert_user, Line 4
There is already an object named 'trigger_insert_user' in the database.

Comment: You can only execute the code once, then the triggers are added and apply to the tables. When you insert new users or apartments the triggers will fire automatically and add the related rows in the ApUser table. If you need to remove the triggers you can do it with `drop trigger trigger_insert_apartment` and `drop trigger trigger_insert_user`

Comment: I updated the code in the answer to include the drop statements.

Answer (score 0):

To address your question about what you'd do to associate apartments with users IF YOU WANTED TO LATER...

If you're restricting which apartments a user has access to view, I would NOT associate them individually to every user.  BUT, if they're manually adding a "watch" on an apartment in your application, then this is ok to do.  If you want to only show them a certain set of apartments, try to group them in a logical way if you can.  So maybe have an ApartmentGroup lookup table:

ApartmentGroup(ApartmentGroupId (Int), ApartmentGroupName varchar(50))

and assign an ApartmentGroupId to each apartment.  Then you can have a join table for ApUser and ApartmentGroup.  That way you're not associating every apartment with every user.

However, if you want to add the apartment to each user still, then in your InsertApartment stored procedure, just insert it into the ApUser table as well.